# Database expression not used in query

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

Can anyone tell me why my expression is not used in the query below?

> SELECT `accountreset`.* FROM `accountreset` WHERE (reset_id = '34') LIMIT 1

```
public function findByResetId($resetId, $model = null) {
    $result = null;
    if (isset($resetId)) {
        $select = $this->getDao()->select(
            array('expiration' => new Zend_Db_Expr('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(expiration)'))
        );
        $select->where('reset_id = ?', $resetId);
        $row = $this->getDao()->fetchRow($select);
        if (null != $row) {
            if (!($model instanceof Stage5_Model_PasswordResetter)) {
                $model = new Stage5_Model_PasswordResetter();
            }
                           // vul het model object
            $model->setResetId($row->reset_id);
            $model->setUserId($row->user_id);
            $model->setExpiration($row->expiration);
            $result = $model;

        }
    }
    return $result;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Zend_Db_Expr` should go into `from()` method instead of `select()`

```
$select = $this->getDao()
               ->select()
               ->from( 
                   $this->getDao()->info('name'), 
                   array('expiration' => new Zend_Db_Expr('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(expiration)'))
                );
```

Comment: The problem here is that now i have to add all the fields i want in my from clause. Because else it will only return one field.

Comment: @sanders you can add a '*' to your array() of fields.